# Java Entity insertion DB change column type

Tags: java, database, entity, persistence

I inherit from a java code with a persistent class named "RELEASE" (javax.persistence dependencies)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"RELEASE\"")
@Converter(name = "booleanConverter", converterClass = BooleanConverter.class)
public class Release implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22)
    private Long id;

    @Convert("booleanConverter")
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 5)
    private Boolean active;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 125)
    private String name;

    // uni-directional many-to-one association to Service
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Service service;
```

And getter and setter associated, I have to change the type of the Id column (Long to String)  because now I make an API request and get a json format response `{key1: "response1, key2 : "response2" , ...}` with string. The new type of number that I get are like "CHG0070132".

How can I change the type without losing my old data?

Comment: Side note: Does the table name _really_ include the double quotes?

Comment: Well, changing the type of `id` in your entity shouldn't be a problem. You'd need to change the type of the column as well though and that depends on what database you're using. In most databases a simple SQL statement should be sufficient and the database should be able to convert the numbers to strings. If this doesn't work you could try creating a new column (e.g. `id_tmp`), converting the content yourself and finally deleting the old `id` column and renaming `id_tmp` to `id`.

Comment: No the table doesn't include the double quotes. Ok, thanks I will try with an SQL statement.

Comment: If the table name doesn't include the double quotes I'd change the annotation to `@Table(name = "RELEASE")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in 2 Parts

1. The DB , you need to manually change the column type of the table in your DB [Check here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)
2. Change the getter Setter and the variable datatype from long to String

Comment: Thanks, I try it but I get some errors like : column type incompatible with referenced column type 
Maybe I can't if the column is the primary key ?

Comment: @nicobin I tried in mysql converting the Primary Key , it worked

Comment: I try again and now I have a problem of privileges I will see with db admin to change that.